# How to retrieve entire Logger output?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have large sets of data (mainly arrays and objects with many elements) and I am trying to log out the entire result to check for bugs. However, in some cases it says     "Logging output too large. Truncating output." Where can I see the output in its entirety? I am working with Map Objects and trying to debug why my calculations don't match Google's output.

Comment: In your situation, as a simple method, how about exporting the data as a text file?

Comment: If you wish to see it in a dialog you can export the text as in a textarea tag as html.

Comment: How would I go about exporting the data as a text file?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `How would I go about exporting the data as a text file?`, although I cannot know your actual script, from `I have large sets of data (mainly arrays and objects with many elements)`, how about using a script of `DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(obj))`? By this, `obj` is exported to the root folder as a text file of `sample.txt`. If I misunderstood your actual script, I apologize.

Comment: No, I think this would work, thanks! I will give this a shot.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolve, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logger.log is limited to the number of lines that it can contain.  However you can make your own logger and save it to a text file.

```
var Log = null;

function testLogger() {
  try {
    Log = new LogFile("testLogFile");
    test1();
    test2();
    throw "done"
  }
  catch(err) {
    Log.log(err);
    Log.save();
  }
}

function test1() {
  Log.log("in test1");
}

function test2() {
  Log.log("in test2");
}

class LogFile {
  constructor (name) {
    if( name === undefined ) name = "_LogFile"
    this.name = name;
    this.text = [];
  }
  log(text) {
    this.text.push(text);
  }
  save() {
    try {
      let text = "";
      this.text.forEach( line => text = text.concat(line,"\n") );

      let files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(this.name);
      let file = null;
      if( files.hasNext() ) {
        file = files.next();
        file.setContent(text);
      }
      else {
        DriveApp.createFile(this.name,text);
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

The text file is shown below.

[image]